# Machine Architecture from Ubuntu OS

Tags: 18.04, 64-bit, cpu-architecture

I have run 'lscpu' in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, I just want to confirm if it's says operation mode is 32 bit and is 64 bit - is this confirmation correct? My expectation is it it possible to install 64 bit OS in my machine? I'm curious .. I am currently running ubuntu 32 bit OS. I want someone who knows better about it.

```
> lscpu

Architecture:        i686
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               42
Model name:          Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B950 @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:            7
CPU MHz:             857.844
CPU max MHz:         2100.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            4190.92
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            2048K
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
```

Comment: You can install 64-bit OS as well, Commands are uname -m, sudo lshw -short

Answer (score 2):

The output shows that the CPU is `Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B950 @ 2.10GHz`.

It supports both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures.

You can install a 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. One weird question but I am asking is it possible to upgrade Ubuntu OS from 32 bit to 64 bit through server?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You need a fresh install. But you can keep your home directory and settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your cores are not different.

Both are 64-bit. Both support 32-bit Operating Systems AND 64-bit Operating Systems, and the various applications thereof.